# Creating custom calendar for ios with events (trips) added over multiple days/months

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, icalendar

I am quite a bit stuck over this issue. In one of my applications, I have to create a custom calendar, showing events-trips associated with multiple dates . The problem is that, actually i need to add the title of the event - trip over multiple dates continuously as shown in attached pic. Right now i am using DPCalendar and the closest I have reached is, displaying event in a single date. but cant add same event - trip title over multiple dates

Any solution or links to any such custom calendar control which supports events over multiple dates is welcome.

Thanks in advance and hoping for a suitable answer ASAP :)[image]

I have customized DPCalender and have achieved this much ...as in image

[image]

Comment: Closing as offtopic: typical "give me code" or recommend a library question.

Comment: No.. its not give me code type question. actually if know, we use cocoa controls or github for getting custom controls. But, I have just mentioned how to customize any such control.

Comment: And what have you tried? What is your specific problem instead of "I don't know how to do that".

Comment: I have customized DPCalendar fully. Just cant set label over multiple dates.see my updated question

Comment: Dis you ever find a solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out custom calendar: https://github.com/tjeerdintveen/Vurig-Calendar

I can see I can add custom bottom lines on date.

Check it out the code:

NSArray *dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];

[calendarView markDates:dates];

You will see bottom line on 1st and on 5th in the application calendar. You can add more objects let say [NSNumber numberWithInt:8] into the same array. Then you will get bottom line on date 8th also.

Hope, It may helpful to you

:)

Comment: Ya the code is close to what I want. But, still the problem remains. How will I add the extend label to 3 dates continously? Like in my refrence image - dates 10,11,12 have a label "Going to New York". How to achieve this?